# Python CSV sum value if they have same ID/name

Tags: python, csv

I want to sum all values that have the same name / ID in a csv file

Right now I am only looking for ID with the name 'company'

**csv file format:**

```
company A, 100 
company B, 200
company A, 300
```

The **end result** I am looking for is:

```
company A, 400
company B, 200
total: 600
```

My code so far:

```py
import csv

name = ''
num = ''
total = 0

with open('xx.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvfile)

    for a in reader:
        if a[0].__contain__('company'):
            name = (a[0])
            num = (a[1])
            total += float(a[1])
            print(str(name) + ', ' + str(num))

            print('total: ' + str(total))
```

Comment: All you are missing is a dictionary with a key based on `name` to accumulate into.

Comment: I'd recommend using `pandas` for more broad CSV/table analytics (group by and sum)

Comment: Your code is not valid Python (indentation).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use `csv` module here. Just read every single line split them from right (`rsplit`) and fill a dictionary like below:

```py
d = {}

with open('your_file.csv') as f:
    # next(f) -  If header needs to be skipped
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)
        d[name] = d.get(name, 0) + int(value)

for k, v in d.items():
    print(f"{k}, {v}")

print(f"total: {sum(d.values())}")
```

output:

```
company A, 400
company B, 200
total: 600
```

In order not to iterate *again* through the dictionary's values to calculate the `total`(I mean in `sum(d.values())` expression), you can do add to `total` while you are printing the items like:

```py
d = {}

with open('new.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)
        d[name] = d.get(name, 0) + int(value)

total = 0
for k, v in d.items():
    total += v
    print(f"{k}, {v}")

print(f"total: {total}")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, CSV typically have commas, and the delimiter for `csv.reader` must be a single character, so I suggest updating your file to properly use commas.

Secondly, to aggregate the companies, you need to store them as you iterate the file. Easiest way is to use a dictionary type.

Then only after you've aggregated everything, should you create a second loop to go over the aggregated values, then print the final total.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

totals = defaultdict(int)
total = 0

with open('companies.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # next (csvfile)  # shown file has no header
   
    for row in reader:
      if not row[0].startswith('company'):
        continue
      name, value = row
      totals[name] += float(value)

total = 0
for name, value in totals.items():
    print(f'{name},{value}')
    total += value

print(f'total: {total}')
```